# print an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, console

I have an ArrayList that contains Event objects.Event Object is charactirised by an ID , Date and a Subject , I am printing out the contents of the Array, I tried

```
ArrayList.get(INDEx)
```

and

```
System.out.println(list)
```

(list is my Arraylist)
but i get as an output :

```
[Metier.Event@368239c8, Metier.Event@9e89d68, 
Metier.Event@3b192d32,Metier.Event@16f65612, Metier.Event@311d617d, 
Metier.Event@7c53a9eb, Metier.Event@ed17bee]
```

instead of the real content of my ArrayList (metier is the name of the package), any help please ?

Comment: Override `toString()` method of `Event` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the `ArrayList`. You are seeing the default `toString()` implementation of the `Event` class of the events contained in the list. Override this method in that class and you should be OK.

Comment: Thank you so much , i forgot overriding toString()